# Visual studio profiler driver error

Tags: visual-studio-2013, windows-7

I'm trying to allow a standard user on Windows 7 Enterprise to use the Visual Studio 2013 Professional performance profiler. I have followed the instructions from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182387.aspx. From an elevated command prompt:

```
cd C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Team Tools\Performance Tools
vsperfcmd /admin:driver,start /admin:service,start
```

However, I get the error:

```
Error VSP1449: Unable to start VSPerfDrv120. The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect. Try using the /admin switch of vsperfcmd from an elevated prompt.
```